# Is my partition to small?

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, disk-usage

My machine popped a message saying that it was maybe lacking space (I didn't did a screenshot but next time it comes I share it with you). It lead to the following window :

[image]

I followed a tutorial to dual-boot with linux and windows. I guess I have to augment my partition but as far as it is the first time I see this I wanted to get your opinion about the situation.

Here is `df -h` output :

```
:~$ df -h

Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev            3,9G     0  3,9G   0% /dev
tmpfs           790M  9,6M  780M   2% /run
/dev/sda5        14G   13G  695M  95% /
tmpfs           3,9G   56M  3,9G   2% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5,0M  4,0K  5,0M   1% /run/lock
tmpfs           3,9G     0  3,9G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sda6        75G   10G   62G  14% /home
tmpfs           790M   88K  790M   1% /run/user/1000
```

And the output of the second command I was asked to provide :

```
/var/www/projet/mooc-symfony$ sudo lsblk -o name,mountpoint,label,size,fstype,uuid&&sudo parted -l
NAME   MOUNTPOINT LABEL         SIZE FSTYPE UUID
sr0                            1024M        
sda                           931,5G        
├─sda4                            1K        
├─sda2            System Reserved
│                               500M ntfs   280C675A0C672254
├─sda7 [SWAP]                   9,4G swap   0e5ab055-f87a-4b00-a4bf-52ab27d9bab6
├─sda5 /                       14,3G ext4   880ac302-9f73-48ad-9883-375b31892f3b
├─sda3                        830,6G ntfs   6A546B90546B5DB7
├─sda1                          487M ext2   5c5ebf21-292d-43d4-91e6-56521da8a4a1
└─sda6 /home                   76,3G ext4   dfbf1fc2-764a-4d76-801a-06d2e6e1b707
Model: ATA TOSHIBA MQ01ABD1 (scsi)
Disk /dev/sda: 1000GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/4096B
Partition Table: msdos
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start   End     Size    Type      File system     Flags
 1      1049kB  512MB   511MB   primary   ext2
 2      512MB   1036MB  524MB   primary   ntfs            boot
 3      1036MB  893GB   892GB   primary   ntfs
 4      893GB   1000GB  107GB   extended
 5      893GB   908GB   15,4GB  logical   ext4
 6      908GB   990GB   81,9GB  logical   ext4
 7      990GB   1000GB  10,1GB  logical   linux-swap(v1)
```

Comment: Please edit your original question to include the output of the following command: `df -h`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the image ou posted, your **root**, "/", partition is 13.2GB.  It's full.  13 Gis is a very small partition for any operating system.  Just browsing the internet with a browser will involve images that can easily add up to a couple of gigs if you spend enough time on the computer.

You can install the OS on 13 Gigs, but in a short period of time, you'll want to install various applications and tools based on your interest.  Each application you install will take up space.

If you save pictures from your camera, that can take up a lot of space also.

I would think for very moderate use, the root partition should be at least 50 Gigs to have space to work and be able to shuffle files you want to keep or delete as you use your system.  If your personal space (your **/home**) folder is on the same partition, you probably should have at least 50 gigs for your personal files.

**Short answer:**

Yes.

In direct response, your 13G partition is too small for normal computer use.  I would recommend at least a combined 100G (personal space and the root OS) for normal computer use.

Many people put their personal space (**/home**) on a separate partition.  If that's case, you should have at least 50G for the **/root** partition and 50G for the **/home** partitions.  If they are on the same partition (having just one partition for Ubuntu) the one partition should be 100G.  Otherwise, you will continue to experience the space issue you are describing.

Comment: Fine, thank you very much ! May you redirect me to a tutorial that helps me to resize it ? I hear that I had something to do first on the Windows boot.

Comment: Everything can be done from Ubuntu.  I'm sure Using Ubuntu is also the easiest.  You can modify the partitions with **gparted**.  You'll have to make the modifications while the drive is not in use.  To do that you'll have to boot to the LiveUSB (the media you used for installing Ubuntu).  Use the "Try Ubuntu" option.  Then run **gparted** from there.  Use the graphical interface to shrink the Windows partition and enlarge the Ubuntu partition.  Having backups of important data is important.

Comment: a number of years ago I used to use 12-15gb for partition sizes; so I could have multiple distros on a 80-160gb disk. they install great, and do well for awhile, but in my experience you want to add extra apps, and normal upgrades, then want to upgrade to the next version - but there isn't enough disk space.  it's not worth it.  use 32gb+

Comment: We can discuss the minimum size of the drive space for a long term Ubuntu system, but I think we can all agree that 13 GiB is way too small except for testing. @Marine1, How much drive space can you make available for Ubuntu's root partition?

Comment: @Marine1The command you use is only showing the size of your mounted partitions.  If you add the output of this command, it'll show all your mounted partitions and also include all your drives and your Windows partitions (which aren't mounted): `sudo lsblk -o name,mountpoint,label,size,fstype,uuid&&sudo parted -l`.

Comment: @sudodus I think I have one tera but it has to  go both for Ubuntu and Windows

Comment: @L.D.James Okay, I noted the procedure to follow. I'm frightened at the moment to do it but I will do it when I go back home. 
I added the otuput of the command `sudo lsblk -o name,mountpoint,label,size,fstype,uuid&&sudo parted -l` above.

Comment: @Marine1 Looking at the output of your command, it appears that you have already basically allocated the type of space I suggested for Ubuntu.  I suggested 100GB.  It's a coincidence that you allocated 15-root, 81-home and 10-swap.  That's 106Gigs.  You don't have to touch your Windows partition.  Just use the **gparted** tool to shrink your `/home` partition by 15 or 20 gigs and grow the `/` partition 15 or 20 gigs.

Comment: @L.D.James Sorry if I'm coming in a little late... but... you want to manage NTFS partitions using Windows own Disk Management application (especially if you expect to be able to boot Windows again) instead of gparted. Save gparted for EXT4/swap partition management.

Comment: @heynnema Don't be sorry for sharing the experience.  I appreciate your sharing.  I hope you don't mind me sharing mine.  I used Windows for 20 years before moving to Unix/Linux.  For the past 15 years I use Linux exclusive except for providing support to Windows users.  When I backup and clean up a Windows computer, I usually attach the harddrive to a Linux computer which is easier and for me more efficient.  When it comes to partitioning, I always use Ubuntu, even for partitioning Windows computers... (continued)

Comment: If I were going to repartition, resize or any other operation on the NTFS partition, I'd do it on an Ubuntu computer, unless there were some circumstances preventing it.  I would find it easier and more efficient.  In this case, if you reread my comment to the OP, I have suggested for him to use **Gparted** to resize his **Linux partitions**.  He has 106 Gigs of space allocated to Linux.  I wouldn't trust Windows to handle those **ext4 and Linux swap partitions**. It appears that Ubuntu **Gparted** is the only way to go in this particular case, which is only involving Linux partitions.

Comment: @L.D.James thanks for your thoughts. Some of the comments were falling into the TL;DR category, so I'm sorry if I missed some of the detail :-) I've seen users try to shrink/extend their **Windows C: drive**, using non-Windows tools, only to find that it doesn't boot any more. Windows needs to know stupid stuff like partition start, and partition end. Haven't you seen that behavior in your travels?

Comment: @heynnema I got downvoted on what I consider a good answer today for not including enough details.  I consider it important to be clear.  Hope I don't get downvoted for trying to be to clear.  But, yes, I see the same thing.  I give lots of support for Windows... just no so much on Stackexchange.  I keep having to fix clients Windows machines because they are using the Windows tools and also having problems.  In this case, if the OP tries to use Windows to format his Linux partition, he'll certainly run into problems.

Comment: @L.D.James I don't see a down vote on your answer here... maybe you refer to another question. And yes, using Windows tools to format his Linux partition is doomed. And speaking of down voting, I had a question just today that I spent **significant** time on answering, and although another answer had exactly 3 sentences, that answer got the accepted vote... even though the user said he followed my answer. Steam'in.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/60928/discussion-between-l-d-james-and-heynnema).